# Best way of customizing SharePoint List forms

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, object-model

What is the best way of customizing SharePoint List forms(NewForm, Edit form, Display form).

1. Application page - object model
2. Visual web part  - object model
3. SharePoint Designer 2010 - ECMA script

Which one will be the test for site level backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many "good" ways to accomplish this.  If you are looking for a replicable way of doing this, using a custom Visual Studio solution would work best.

If you are looking for a way to do it on a single list, you could do it with SharePoint Designer or with InfoPath Designer.

With more details, we could provide a better recommendation.